# large tab delimited file manipulation in shell

Tags: shell, if-statement, awk, tabs

I have a big file with 200000 rows and 150000 columns. I want to switch two columns with one another if the third column starts with a string.

Input:

```
sr1  .  A  B  x|y:abc:xyz 
sr2  .  B  D  y|y:abc:xyz
sr3  .  G  F  x|y:abc:xyz
sr4  .  Z  C  y|x:abc:xyz
sr5  .  Z  D  x|y:abc:xyz
```

Output if 5th column starts with x|y

```
sr1  .  B  A  x|y:abc:xyz
sr2  .  B  D  y|y:abc:xyz
sr3  .  F  G  x|y:abc:xyz
sr4  .  Z  C  y|x:abc:xyz
sr5  .  D  Z  x|y:abc:xyz
```

Can I do it in shell or using awk?

Comment: On SO we encourage users to post their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: While you could do this with shell, you shouldn't (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). You can and should trivially do it with awk.

Comment: `gawk '$5~/^x\|y/{t=$4;$4=$3;$3=t}1' input`